# Complex select statment using Mysql

Tags: mysql, join, select

I dont't now how to explain but i have two table in my database.

- tab 1: service
- tab 2: department

service table:

```
idService
serviceName
department_ID
is_deleted
```

department table:

```
departmentId
departmenetName
is_deleted
```

I want select all services with the departement name but with departement also if there is no service assigned to it.
if there is no service assigned to a departement then the flelds will be shown but i must have null or equivalent in idService field.
The result would be like this :

| serviceID | serviceName | departmentId | departmenetName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |
| 1 | IT | 2 | SI |
|  |  |  |  |
| 2 | Maintenance | 6 | Mechanical |
|  |  |  |  |
| 3 | Maintenance | 6 | Mechanical |
|  |  |  |  |
| 4 | Opt Manager | 7 | Finance |
|  |  |  |  |
| 5 | Instrument | 5 | Electric |
|  |  |  |  |
| NULL | NULL | 1 | Civil |
|  |  |  |  |
| 8 | Agro | NULL | NULL |
| _________ | ___________ | ____________ | _______________ |

I have tried all kind of join options but I couldn't find the logic behind.
I use Mysql as DB
Any idea please ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try using an union between the left joined  tables  whit and without service

```
    select a.serviceID, a.serviceNam, b.departmentId, b.departmenetName
    from service a
    left join department b on a.department_ID = b.departmentId 
    UNION 
    select null, null, b.departmentId, b.departmenetName
    from department b 
    left join service a a.department_ID = b.departmentId  
    where a.serviceID is null
```

Comment: The first time it shown some conflict "mixing" some fields but after playing with NULL attribute in the second select everythink is well.
Your are like a gift thank you very very much. please how can i find a good tutorial/paper about the usage of null as field in select statements ? i never see it before!

Comment: @AisthesisCronos  As for a good tutorial I am not able to advise you .. when I started using SQL they weren't there .. everything I know I learned by studying the reference manuals of the various databases that I used .. I suggest you take a good look at the mysql reference .. it's a bit more difficult but you find everything